# Reverse order of bar chart colours while keeping legend order and colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, pie-chart

I am working on ggplot2 in R, and have used automatic colouring for the plot. It plots stacked bar charts and then converts them to the pie chart. Here is the code:

```
ggplot(data=reg_sub_rj_reviewed, aes(x=factor(1), stat="bin", fill=`project-effort`)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill") + # Stacked bar chart
  facet_grid(facets=. ~ strength) + # Side by side bar chart
  coord_polar(theta="y") + # side by side pie chart
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank()
        ) +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "Graded Result (code quality)",
    title = "Graded Result Broken Down By Coding Effort",
    fill = "Project Effort"
  ) +
  NULL
```

The resulting image is:
[image]

I would like the pie chart to have the same order of colours as the legend (when you look at pie chart in a clock-wise way). Start from 12 o'clock and go clockwise: first colour should be orange, then brown, then green etc (currently clockwise plot of pie chart is from the pink (last value!), then purple etc).

PS Also, how can I get rid of the 1 being plotted on the left side of the chart?

A reproducible example of the above issue, is pretty much for any pie chart, for example:

```
slices <- c(10, 12, 4, 16, 8) 
lbls <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th")
pie(slices,labels = lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)),
   main="Pie Chart of Countries")
```

Result:
[image]

Humanly I'd expect clockwise numbering 1st, then 2nd (not 5th) in the image, i.e. not anticlockwise. (Sorry I don't know why the image is coming up so huge).

Comment: Can you please add some example data to make this question reproducible?

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring I have added a simple reproducible example of the same issue. (How do I make that image smaller? Apologies it is coming up so huge lol).

Answer (score 1):

```
pi_df <- data.frame(slices, lbls)

library(dplyr); library(forcats)
pi_df %>%
  mutate(lbls = fct_inorder(lbls) %>% fct_rev) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=slices, y = factor(1), fill = lbls)) +
  geom_col() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

If we add these lines:

```
... + 
geom_text(aes(label = slices), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
theme_void() # to remove axis lines and background shading
```

we can get the values labeled inside each slice. We have to use the `position` argument so that `geom_text` can know that we want our text labels stacked incrementally around the pie, same as the slices are stacked automatically in `geom_col()`. `vjust` says we want the labels halfway into each slice, not at either side edge.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Jon  this solves the problem nicely! Do you know how to add values of slices into each of the pie sections? Just to overlay the pie sections with numbers responsible for giving that piece of the pie?

Comment: add `geom_text(aes(label = slices), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @Jon! Also how can we drop the outer white circle and its values, if that's possible?

Comment: `+ theme_void()`

Answer (score 0):

Try `aes(x="", ...` in `ggplot` and maybe adjust `start = ...` or `direction = ...` in `coor_polar`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).